# How to jump to the last page from URL link?

Tags: url, hyperlink

Here is oldest page of comments in my profile:

https://math.stackexchange.com/users/717650/etemon?tab=activity&sort=comments&page=27

As you can see in order to open this page I should have "page=27" at the end. But for example if number of pages of my comments exceed 27 then this link wouldn't go the page of my oldest comment. I'm wondering is it possible to change the URL so that, it opens the oldest page of comments? I tried writing for example "page=99999" at the end but it opens a page with no comments in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are asking not specifically about math.stackexchange.com, but in a more general case.

There's no way to know *if* this is possible by just looking at urls. In most cases I would expect there to be no way to go immediately to the last page in a collection.